# How to can we run specific test cases in robot framework

Tags: robotframework, testcase

I am new to Robot Framework and writing the test cases in it.
I have a test suite name "testSuiteTrial.robot" which have 50 test cases .When i am running the test suite , few test cases are getting failed.I don't want to run the full test suite again.So i am looking for an approach for running only the failed test cases from test suite.

Any help on that

Comment: How do you run the tests? Do you use RIDE?

Comment: Yes , i am using ride

Comment: This is a typical read the manual situation. The Robot Framework User Guide is a very well maintained source of information for these types of questions. I strongly suggest you search it for keywords whenever you have a question.

Answer (score 2):

Look to the documentation [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#configuring-execution), chapter "Selecting test cases"

There are options there:

- By test suite and test case names
- By tag names
- Re-executing failed test cases

And maybe having 50 test cases in one suite is not a very good idea? In our team we have a limitation 10 cases for suite (except data-driven tests) cause of when there are more suites become very long and hard to maintain.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for sharing the input. i will keep this thing in mind for future test suite creation.

Comment: I can able to run the failed test cases by the test cases names.Thanks